# Late 70's or early 80's horror anthology?

Tags: story-identification, tv

Trying to find the name of a late 70's or early 80's tv horror anthology show. One story I remember was about a baseball pitcher who loses his hand or arm in car crash and gets the arm of an executed murder. The pitcher then starts to get the urge to kill.

Comment: http://blackholereviews.blogspot.co.uk/2009/08/body-parts-1991-gory-horror-car-chase.html

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're referring to the anthology horror film "[Body Bags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_Bags_%28film%29)" starring Mark Hamill.

The third segment ('*EYE*') features a baseball player who receives an **eye transplant** and slowly evolves into a serial killer;

> *Brent Matthews is a Major League Baseball player whose life and career takes a turn for the worse when he gets into a serious car
>   accident in which his right eye is gouged out. Unwilling to admit that
>   his career is over, he jumps at the chance when a doctor tells him
>   about an experimental surgical procedure to replace his eye with one
>   from a recently deceased person which can restore his sight. After the
>   surgery, Brent can see through his new eye, and is overjoyed at this
>   miracle. But, soon after, Brent begins to see things out of his new
>   eye that others cannot see, and it puts him and his wife Cathy in
>   danger as Brent begins having nightmares of killing women and having
>   sex with them. Brent seeks out the doctor who tells him that the donor
>   of his new eye was a recently executed serial killer and necrophile
>   who killed several young women, and then had sex with their dead
>   bodies. Brent becomes convinced that the spirit of the dead killer is
>   slowly taking over his body through his eye and enabling him to resume
>   killing women. After Brent blacks out and wakes up near a crime scene
>   where another young woman is killed, he flees back to his house where
>   he tells the skeptic Cathy about what is going on with him. Just then
>   the spirit of the killer emerges and attempts to kill Cathy as well.
>   Cathy fights back, subduing him long enough for Brent to re-emerge.
>   Realizing that it will only be a matter of time before the killer
>   reemerges again, Brent cuts out his donated eye, severing his link
>   with the killer, but he dies afterwards from bleeding to death.*

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, but I finally found out the name of the show. It was Quinn Martins Tales of the Unexpected(1977). The pitcher was played by Ricky Nelson.